# Log a message from HTML input with NodeJS/socketio

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, socket.io

I'd like it so whenever I type something in a input box and click send it logs in the NodeJS console what has been send, for example a user types "Hello world" and then clicks "Send message to console" and then in the console it will say "Hello world".

I have really no idea on how I should do this

Answer (score 0):

You should read socketio doc: http://socket.io/docs/

On the client side you send the data like this:

```
socket.emit('inputbox', data)
```

On the server side inside the "io.on" callback you use:

```
socket.on('inputbox', function (data) {
    console.log(data)
  })
```

There is also a very detailed tutorial that should get you started: http://socket.io/get-started/chat/

Comment: So I would gather the input value with Javascript and then send it to the socket which will pick up the signal and send it to the NodeJS console? Let's give it a shot (:!

Comment: If you follow the tutorial I linked then you will learn exactly what you need. You should also keep the browser debug window open and check for any error message. The full code is right here: https://github.com/rauchg/chat-example

Comment: make sure that your script is working correctly and add something like `console.log("starting...");` at the beginning of your script.